# Each function jquery for selecting all checkboxes within multiple lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of checkboxes within multiple ul tags. I want to uncheck and check all using an href for each list. (There will be several lists, here I have provided HTML for two lists) The code does not work in that the checkboxes are not all checked or unchecked on click.. Can anyone help please?

Here is what I have tried so far in a JSFIDDLE

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="btn-group options" id="checkboxes-div-1" class="checkbox-div">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle open-first" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" >
           Select one or more options <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu check-first" id="close-out" role="menu" name="form3">
           <li class="option">
             <a class="checkall show-cross-2" href="#">Check all</a>
             <a class="uncheckall" href="#">Uncheck all</a>
           </li>
           <li><strong>Group 1</strong></li>
           <li class="option">
             <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
               <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Option #1 for group 1
             </label>
           </div>
         </li>
         <li class="option">
           <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
             <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Option #2 for group 1
           </label>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="option">
         <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
           <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Option #3 for group 1
         </label>
       </div>
     </li>
     <li><strong>Group 2</strong></li>
     <li class="option">
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
         <input type="checkbox" >Forum
       </label>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li class="option">
     <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
       <input type="checkbox">Ipsum
     </label>
   </div>
 </li>
 <li class="option">
   <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox">Dorol
   </label>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div> <!--/.btn-group-->
</div> <!--/.col-xs-6-->



</div> <!--/.third-row-->

 <div class="row fourth-row">

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="btn-group options hide" id="checkboxes-div-2" class="checkbox-div">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle open-second" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" >
           Select one or more options <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu check-second" id="close-out" role="menu" name="form3">
           <li class="option">
             <a class="checkall show-cross-2" href="#">Check all</a>
             <a class="uncheckall" href="#">Uncheck all</a>
           </li>
           <li><strong>Group 1</strong></li>
           <li class="option">
             <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
               <input type="checkbox" >Option #1 for group 1
             </label>
           </div>
         </li>
         <li class="option">
           <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
             <input type="checkbox" >Option #2 for group 1
           </label>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="option">
         <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
           <input type="checkbox" >Option #3 for group 1
         </label>
       </div>
     </li>
     <li><strong>Group 2</strong></li>
     <li class="option">
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
         <input type="checkbox">Forum
       </label>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li class="option">
     <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
       <input type="checkbox">Ipsum
     </label>
   </div>
 </li>
 <li class="option">
   <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox">Dorol
   </label>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div> <!--/.btn-group-->
</div> <!--/.col-xs-6-->

</div> <!--/.fourth-row-->
```

My jquery:

```
$.each($('.checkbox-div'), function () {
      $(".checkall").click(function() {
           $(":checkbox.only-this").attr("checked", true);
      })
      $(".uncheckall").click(function() {
           $(":checkbox").attr("checked", false);
      })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2yLq61o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```js
$(".checkall").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
})
$(".uncheckall").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="btn-group options" id="checkboxes-div-1" class="checkbox-div">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle open-first" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select one or more options <span class="caret"></span>

        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu check-first" id="close-out" role="menu" name="form3">
            <li class="option"> <a class="checkall show-cross-2" href="#">Check all</a>
 <a class="uncheckall" href="#">Uncheck all</a>

            </li>
            <li><strong>Group 1</strong>

            </li>
            <li class="option">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Option #1 for group 1</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="option">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Option #2 for group 1</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="option">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="only-this show-cross-2">Option #3 for group 1</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><strong>Group 2</strong>

            </li>
            <li class="option">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox">Forum</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="option">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox">Ipsum</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="option">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox">Dorol</label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.btn-group-->
</div>
<!--/.col-xs-6-->
</div>
<!--/.third-row-->
<div class="row fourth-row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="btn-group options hide" id="checkboxes-div-2" class="checkbox-div">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle open-second" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select one or more options <span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu check-second" id="close-out" role="menu" name="form3">
                <li class="option"> <a class="checkall show-cross-2" href="#">Check all</a>
 <a class="uncheckall" href="#">Uncheck all</a>

                </li>
                <li><strong>Group 1</strong>

                </li>
                <li class="option">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">Option #1 for group 1</label>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="option">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">Option #2 for group 1</label>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="option">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">Option #3 for group 1</label>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><strong>Group 2</strong>

                </li>
                <li class="option">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">Forum</label>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="option">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">Ipsum</label>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="option">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">Dorol</label>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.btn-group-->
    </div>
    <!--/.col-xs-6-->
</div>
<!--/.fourth-row-->
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more way, more strictly connected to DOM structure:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2yLq61o/3/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".checkall").click(function()
    {
        handleOptions(this, true);
    });

    $(".uncheckall").click(function()
    {
        handleOptions(this, false);
    });

    function handleOptions(element, value)
    {
        var optionBlocks = $(element).parent().siblings('.option');
        optionBlocks.find("input").prop("checked", value);
    }
});
```